JPA @Modifying Update query with where clause relations error
Im having a weird case where I have a repository with a very simple query .
@Modifying
@Query("update Test t set t.worker = :workerToEdit where (t.product.deleted = false)")
void editTest(
    Worker workerToEdit
);

When I execute this i get this error.
`024-08-09 08:36:15.688 DEBUG 81121 --- [io-28080-exec-4] org.hibernate.SQL                        : update test cross join  set worker_id=? where deleted=0
Hibernate: update test cross join  set worker_id=? where deleted=0
2024-08-09 08:36:15.689 TRACE 81121 --- [io-28080-exec-4] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [10]
2024-08-09 08:36:15.692  WARN 81121 --- [io-28080-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
2024-08-09 08:36:15.693 ERROR 81121 --- [io-28080-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set worker_id=10 where deleted=0' at line 1
2024-08-09 08:36:15.746 ERROR 81121 --- [io-28080-exec-4] c.d.a.controller.ErrorControllerAdvice   : could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:279) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:253) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]`
As you can see is omitting the relation here internally. If we do the same but in a Select without using @Modifying works perfectly, so seems that the relation in the model is properly done.
Its an expected behaviour when its a UPDATE?
Im using springboot starter 2.1.7.RELEASE AND Mysql 5.7, but its also failing its mysql 8
I have tried to upgrade to the maximum Jpa and hibernate that would work with my version. But didn't work neither.

The query seems to include the correct set and where parts: set worker_id=10 where deleted=0. Can you see what the entire statement is by turning JPA query logging on?

@RobSpoor The deleted has to reference the product and the cross join its not mentioning product anywhere. Seems that its ommiting product
This is not correct
"update test cross join set worker_id=? where deleted=0"

I see, I had overlooked the .product part. It appears that Hibernate indeed cannot do this properly. The created query a) omits the table to join on, and b) sets deleted on the wrong table.

Can you try this: update Test t join t.product p set t.worker = :workerToEdit where (p.deleted = false)? I haven't tried it so I can't guarantee it works.

@RobSpoor expecting "set", found 'join' near line 1, column 49 [update com.XXXX.Test t join t.product p set t.worker = :workerToEdit where (p.deleted = false)] Its not linking this syntax. This would work in a normal SQL query but not JPQL... With the param native query its doing the same for some reason. Its very strange, i could use a raw query but loses a bit the point of jpa.

Maybe this helps.

@Karsten with that answer, works. but that subquery in my case its not optimal. For this case i will use a rawquery with joins etc. But I still think that this case should work without this many workarounds
